# detect content size using jquery and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a slideshow page for service monitoring purpose.  On the page, there will be a serie of DIVs whose height will be same but width varys (with its `max-width` property set).  These DIVs are displayed using `inline-block`.

My question is, say I have 200 cards to show, and the monitor can only display a few dozen.   Without knowing the display port's size, and each card's exact size (because they are different), how can I know how many cards to display on a slide so that the scrollbars won't be shown?

Pseudocode like:

```
function showSlide(cards, index) {
    clearSlide()
    while (index < cards.length) {
        showCard(cards[index])
        index++
        if (noMoreSpaceOnPage()) {
            break
        }
    }
    return index
}

cards = getCards()
var index = 0
setInterval(30000, function() {
        next = showSlide(cards, index)
        if (next >= index) {
            index = 0
        } else {
            index = next
        }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get the viewport width (`document.documentElement.clientWidth` is the window/frame width in pixels, without scrollbar) and also width of  each card (`offsetWidth` property):

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll("div");

const viewportWidth = () =>  document.documentElement.clientWidth;

const cardWidth = card => card.offsetWidth;

const cardsThatWillFit = (cards, viewportWidth) => {
  let remainingWidth = viewportWidth;
  const fittableCards = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) { // this is uglier than forEach, but it supports break, so…
    remainingWidth = remainingWidth - cardWidth(cards[i]);
    if (remainingWidth > 0) {
      fittableCards.push(cards[i]);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  };
  return fittableCards;
};


const logInfo = () => {
  console.log("viewport width:", viewportWidth());
  cards.forEach((card, index) => console.log(`card ${index + 1} width:`, cardWidth(card)));
  console.log("cards that will fit:", cardsThatWillFit(cards, viewportWidth()).map((card, index) => index + 1).join(" "));
  console.log("-------------")
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  cards.forEach(card => card.style.width = Math.random() * 8 + "em");
  logInfo();
})

logInfo();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav div {
  padding: 3em;
  border: 1px solid hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  width: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button>randomize widths</button>
<nav>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
</nav>
```

Don't forget to add any margins between cards to the calculation. And recalculate on window resizes if needed.

Comment: Your example seems to handle the width of cards only, how about height?